# Pass Buffer to ChildProcess Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, subprocess

Here I have on Node.Js where I want to do Image Processing in a Sub Process.

As you will see I take the file `image.jpg` and want to write it back to `hello.jpg` in a subprocess:

```
var node = require('child_process').spawn('node',['-i']);
var fs = require('fs');

node.stdout.on('data',function(data) {
  var fs = require('fs');
    var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

    gm(data)
     .resize(500, 500)
     .toBuffer("jpg", function(err, buffer) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        fs.writeFile("hello.jpg", buffer);  
      }
   });
});


var buffer = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/image.jpg");
node.stdin.write(buffer);
```

However when I run this file I get this error:

[Error: Stream yields empty buffer]

**For me it seems like the buffer is not passed correctly to the subprocess?**
What do I wrong? **What can I do to run Image Processing in a subtask.** For me its important that Its not read from a file in the subprocess. Because I want to read one File again and then send the buffer to several subprocesses that do Image Transformations. Thanks!

Comment: `gm` already doing it in subprocess.(asynchoronously)

Comment: Hi @befzz, thats great could you please provide me a link where it says this? And write it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: But its not async right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744288/asynchronous-graphicsmagick-for-node/17745079#17745079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing any work in a subprocess. It is just `node -i` and nothing else. All your image processing happens in the main process.

To fix it, you can actually run another Node process and give it some script to execute, say `worker.js`:

```
process.stdin.on('data',function(data) {
  var fs = require('fs');
    var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

    gm(data)
     .resize(500, 500)
     .toBuffer("jpg", function(err, buffer) {
      if (err) {
    console.log(err);
      }else{
    fs.writeFile("hello.jpg", buffer);
      }
   });
});
```

Then you would create a subprocess from your main script:

```
var node = require('child_process').spawn('node', ['worker.js']);
var fs = require('fs');

var buffer = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/image.jpg");
node.stdin.end(buffer);
```

Note that I used `node.stdin.end` in the last line to terminate the worker.

Take a look at [cluster](https://iojs.org/api/cluster.html) module for the alternative approach.